# Floating Toolbar for Macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to make a floating toolbar to house my macros, but with limited success. This is the code I have so far.

```
Sub FloatingToolBar()

Dim ComBar As CommandBar
Dim ComBarContrl As CommandBarControl

On Error Resume Next
CommandBars("My Toolbar").Delete
On Error GoTo 0

Set ComBar = CommandBars.Add(Name:="My Toolbar", Position:=msoBarFloating, 
Temporary:=True)
ComBar.Visible = True

Set ComBarContrl = ComBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
With ComBarContrl
    .Caption = "Macro1"
    .Style = msoButtonCaption
    .TooltipText = "Run Macro1"
    .OnAction = "DeleteandReformat"
End With



End Sub
```

It runs without erroring out, but does not create a toolbar. Any thoughts?

Comment: Floating toolbars are gone since Office 2007

Comment: oh, bummer. Thanks for letting me know!